# Shifted caption in longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I have a table that marks if the table is moved to the next page. But for some reason, the title of the table moves to the right. What's the reason? The code and the screenshot below.

Thanks in advance.

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{10cm}}
\label{tab:Table caption positioning}
\caption{Table caption shifted from center by unknown reason}\\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\hline
\textbf{Cell11}  &  Cell12\\
\textbf{Cell21}  &  Cell22\\
\textbf{Cell31}  &  Cell32\\
\textbf{Cell41}  &  Cell42\\
\textbf{Cell51}  &  Cell52\\
\textbf{Cell61}  &  Cell62\\
\textbf{Cell71}  &  Cell72\\
\textbf{Cell81}  &  Cell82\\
\textbf{Cell91}  &  Cell92\\
\textbf{Cell101}  &  Cell102\\
\textbf{Cell111}  &  Cell112\\
\textbf{Cell121}  &  Cell122\\
\textbf{Cell131}  &  Cell132\\
\textbf{Cell141}  &  Cell142\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image: shifted caption in longtable]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you run LaTeX *twice*?

Comment: @Mico Yes, many times.

Comment: You have to provide an MWE. I compiled your table using Overleaf, and it compiled fine. I assume you are using the caption package (or KOMA-script) without correct options.

Comment: Table label should always be after `caption`.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your longtable using Overleaf, and it compiled fine. I assume you are using the caption package (or KOMA-script) without correct options. (I moved the label inside the caption to get rid of an error message and assure that the reference will be correct)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, lmodern}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{10cm}}
\caption{Table caption shifted from center by unknown reason\label{tab:Table caption positioning}}\\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\hline
\textbf{Cell11}  &  Cell12\\
\textbf{Cell21}  &  Cell22\\
\textbf{Cell31}  &  Cell32\\
\textbf{Cell41}  &  Cell42\\
\textbf{Cell51}  &  Cell52\\
\textbf{Cell61}  &  Cell62\\
\textbf{Cell71}  &  Cell72\\
\textbf{Cell81}  &  Cell82\\
\textbf{Cell91}  &  Cell92\\
\textbf{Cell101}  &  Cell102\\
\textbf{Cell111}  &  Cell112\\
\textbf{Cell121}  &  Cell122\\
\textbf{Cell131}  &  Cell132\\
\textbf{Cell141}  &  Cell142\\
\textbf{Cell11}  &  Cell12\\
\textbf{Cell21}  &  Cell22\\
\textbf{Cell31}  &  Cell32\\
\textbf{Cell41}  &  Cell42\\
\textbf{Cell51}  &  Cell52\\
\textbf{Cell61}  &  Cell62\\
\textbf{Cell71}  &  Cell72\\
\textbf{Cell81}  &  Cell82\\
\textbf{Cell91}  &  Cell92\\
\textbf{Cell101}  &  Cell102\\
\textbf{Cell111}  &  Cell112\\
\textbf{Cell121}  &  Cell122\\
\textbf{Cell131}  &  Cell132\\
\textbf{Cell141}  &  Cell142\\\textbf{Cell11}  &  Cell12\\
\textbf{Cell21}  &  Cell22\\
\textbf{Cell31}  &  Cell32\\
\textbf{Cell41}  &  Cell42\\
\textbf{Cell51}  &  Cell52\\
\textbf{Cell61}  &  Cell62\\
\textbf{Cell71}  &  Cell72\\
\textbf{Cell81}  &  Cell82\\
\textbf{Cell91}  &  Cell92\\
\textbf{Cell101}  &  Cell102\\
\textbf{Cell111}  &  Cell112\\
\textbf{Cell121}  &  Cell122\\
\textbf{Cell131}  &  Cell132\\
\textbf{Cell141}  &  Cell142\\\textbf{Cell11}  &  Cell12\\
\textbf{Cell21}  &  Cell22\\
\textbf{Cell31}  &  Cell32\\
\textbf{Cell41}  &  Cell42\\
\textbf{Cell51}  &  Cell52\\
\textbf{Cell61}  &  Cell62\\
\textbf{Cell71}  &  Cell72\\
\textbf{Cell81}  &  Cell82\\
\textbf{Cell91}  &  Cell92\\
\textbf{Cell101}  &  Cell102\\
\textbf{Cell111}  &  Cell112\\
\textbf{Cell121}  &  Cell122\\
\textbf{Cell131}  &  Cell132\\
\textbf{Cell141}  &  Cell142\\\textbf{Cell11}  &  Cell12\\
\textbf{Cell21}  &  Cell22\\
\textbf{Cell31}  &  Cell32\\
\textbf{Cell41}  &  Cell42\\
\textbf{Cell51}  &  Cell52\\
\textbf{Cell61}  &  Cell62\\
\textbf{Cell71}  &  Cell72\\
\textbf{Cell81}  &  Cell82\\
\textbf{Cell91}  &  Cell92\\
\textbf{Cell101}  &  Cell102\\
\textbf{Cell111}  &  Cell112\\
\textbf{Cell121}  &  Cell122\\
\textbf{Cell131}  &  Cell132\\
\textbf{Cell141}  &  Cell142\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem is fixed by putting "\label" inside the "\caption" as you did, i. e. changing

"\label{tab:Table caption positioning}
\caption{Table caption shifted from center by unknown reason}\\"

to

"\caption{Table caption shifted from center by unknown reason\label{tab:Table caption positioning}}\\"

Comment: It also  work correctly with `\caption{Table caption shifted from center by unknown reason}\label{tab:Table caption positioning}\\ `